# Opening a PDF document in a WebBrowser fails .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control

I have a user control in wpf that I use in my main WPF app:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Utilities.Controls.WebBrowser.MyWebBrowser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
          <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" />  
</UserControl>
```

And I import it to my main Window app:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="My.Apps.WPF.wMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
    xmlns:wbr="clr-namespace:My.Utilities.Controls.WebBrowser;assembly=My.Utilities.Controls">

<!-- stuff -->

<wbr:MyWebBrowser Visibility="{Binding PDFVisibility}" HtmlText="{Binding PDFSelected}"/>


</Window>
```

**View Model**:

```
private byte[] bytArray;

public string PDFSelected
{
    get
    {
        string PDFFileName = CreatePDFFile(bytArray);

        return string.Format("{0}#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&scrollbar=1&view=FitV", PDFFileName);
    }
}


private string CreatePDFFile(myArrayOfBytes)
{
   string pdfFile = @"C:\testpdf.pdf";

   File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFile, myArrayOfBytes);

   return pdfFile;
}
```

I have checked that PDF file is correctly created as "C:\testpdf.pdf" and I also can open it using Adobe Reader DC without problems.

But when I send it to WPF WebBrowser object through PDFSelected property it cannot open and below error message is shown:

> There is a problem with adobe acrobat / reader. if it is running, please exit and try again. (1:1).

I have installed in my system following Adobe products:

- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015.010.20060
- Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2015 (Classic) | 2015.006.30280 (trial 30 days)

Comment: From what I can see is that your app is not closing another instance of PDF viewer or file is locked and Adobe can't read it. There is also option in adobe to disable the security for pdf files. Have a look at [this](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/enhanced.html).

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have debugged it and see that the problem was in the parameters being passed. So I have passed only the file name without parameters and then it started to work. Then to detect which parameter was the culprit, I have passed one by one, try and error. My surprise was that after being passed all parameters again, now it works (I do not understand). But I have found a problem, now it opens with Adobe Reader 2015 but not with 2018 (using same parameters). Why? Any ideas?